# PHP Cookies are not set

Tags: php

i have been banging my head to wall for last 12 hours or so but i cant find whats going wrong. i want to set cookie but cant. getting fedup with this now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
$cookie_name = "mysiterandomuser";
$cookie_value = "justanotheruser";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
?>

<html>
<body>

<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
     echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
     echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
     echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> You might have to reload the page to see the new value of the cookie.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php clearly states `Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output, including <html> and <head> tags as well as any whitespace.` Poor head.

Comment: Why is this also tagged with javascript and mysql?

Comment: @fvu  i tried every possible way. i shifted html tags below the php code. have been sitting next to my computer and reading the documentations for last 8 hours or so. read ever website that suggest how to set cookies. i thought i was doing something wrong until i copied and pasted the exact code from w3schools. it saw it working on their site at one point so copied and after that nothings working.

Answer (score 4):

You can't set cookies after headers/content have already been sent. You need to set your cookies first.

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "mysiterandomuser";
$cookie_value = "justanotheruser";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
     echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
     echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
     echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> You might have to reload the page to see the new value of the cookie.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did the same as the answer here. But worst is that it worked for me after the html started output too...

Comment: @Rob M. i tried every possible way. i shifted html tags below the php code. have been sitting next to my computer and reading the documentations for last 8 hours or so. read ever website that suggest how to set cookies. i thought i was doing something wrong until i copied and pasted the exact code from w3schools. it saw it working on their site at one point so copied and after that nothings working.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)...

> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that
>   the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully
>   set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie
>   expires.

Change this...

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "mysiterandomuser";
$cookie_value = "justanotheruser";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
?>
```

To This...

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
$cookie_name = "mysiterandomuser";
$cookie_value = "justanotheruser";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
}
?>
```

Reason for this is that you are setting the cookie on every page view.

Forgive me for asking, but are cookies enabled in your browser?

Comment: i closed the browser several times after visiting.. but still nothing happens. its still the same s going on. tried in edge, ie, chrome, firefox. i need to fix this but its getting crazier here

Comment: @Francisco I have updated my answer. See if it works for you. Remember, you will have to reload the page

Comment: thats negative! i copied and pasted all your above code but just cant. echoes out nothing. i refreshed my page several times and even closed brower and opened again but nothing. And yes cookies are enables in my broswer. i saw cookies in settings on chrome.               <?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
$cookie_name = "mysiterandomuser";
$cookie_value = "justanotheruser";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
}
echo $_COOKIE['cookie_name'];
?>

Comment: I've copied and pasted your code into a script on my dev box. Your code works flawlessly for me. Must be something wrong with your browser settings or php.ini config.